# Deployed the Source but have UNCHANGED DeployClass Status

Tags: apex, visualforce

i'm having some trouble here. When i deploy the code i get no errors in my screen, but after that, in the OUTPUT tab, it says my code in UNCHANGED intead of CHANGED. Could you guys help me please?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have not saved the file. Note the dot to the right of the filename in Visual Studio Code, which indicates unsaved changes.

Comment: Man, you are a lifesaver! Thank you very much, i'll pay more attention to details, thaks m8.

Comment: I'm getting another problem now, the "Empty block" message!

Comment: @FelipeSimoni
Thats coming from PMD ruleset configured in your IDE. That won't stop you from deploying changes to your org though. For fixing this specific issue, you can remove the empty constructor as compiler will always generate an empty constructor if you dont have any parameterized constructor defined in your apex class.